# How do I switch users with their groups groups in Python?

Tags: python, users, group, non-root-user, python3

How do I switch to an admin-user account from this python script named `root_and_user.py`  that was run with `doas` or `sudo`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from os import geteuid, seteuid
from subprocess import run
from sys import argv, exit

def touch(fname):
    with open(fname, 'a') as f:
        pass

#run this doas ./root_and_user.py 

if geteuid() == 0:
    touch("1.owned-by-root")
    touch("2.owned-by-root")
    seteuid(1000) 
    touch("1.owned-by-admin-user")
    touch("2.owned-by-admin-user")
```

I've written my own custom function, also called `touch()` that creates an empty file. `1000` is the id of `admin_user`. When I run the script with `sudo` or `doas` the files `1.owned-by-admin-user` and `2.owned-by-admin-user` are created but they still belong to the group `root` - although being owned by `admin_user`. My aim is to accomplish that `1.owned-by-admin-user` and `2.owned-by-admin-user` are not only owned by `admin_user` but also have a group `admin_user`. How might I accomplish that?

Comment: Use setegid/setegid to set the group

Answer (score 1):

The `os.chown()` method can be used to modify the group ownership of files generated by your Python script. Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from os import geteuid, seteuid
from subprocess import run
from sys import argv, exit

def touch(fname):
    with open(fname, 'a'):
        os.utime(fname, None)

#run this doas ./root_and_user.py 

if geteuid() == 0:
    touch("1.owned-by-root")
    touch("2.owned-by-root")
    seteuid(1000) 
    os.chown("1.owned-by-root", 1000, 1000) # change owner and group to admin_user
    os.chown("2.owned-by-root", 1000, 1000) # change owner and group to admin_user
    touch("1.owned-by-admin-user")
    touch("2.owned-by-admin-user")
    seteuid(0)
    os.chown("1.owned-by-admin-user", 1000, 1000) # change owner and group to admin_user
    os.chown("2.owned-by-dmin-user", 1000, 1000) # change owner and group to admin_user
```